# Unclear behaviour of pandas to_datetime when format is specified

Tags: python, pandas, format

I don't understand the behaviour of pandas.to_datetime().

When I try:

```
pandas.to_datetime('2020-01-20',format=r'%Y/%m/%d')
```

it returns:

```
Timestamp('2020-01-20 00:00:00')
```

whereas I was expecting an exception. I think the function is using the format argument as a hint and not a rigid format but this isn't in the documentation. I tried explicitly setting `errors='raise'` but there was no effect.

Is this a misunderstanding on my part, a documentation issue, or a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Why were you expecting an exception with - pandas.to_datetime('2020-01-20',format=r'%Y/%m/%d')? I am not able to see any issue, unless I am missing anything

Comment: Why would you expect an exception? As you have specified that you require the format to be in Year followed by Month followed by Date, and you have given your custom date in that order itself

Comment: The format specifies a slash delimited date. The value is dash delimited so I expected an exception.